# MVVM Bind model to custom control code behind

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

I am building WinUI app with Win2D canvas.

Introduction info:

- I'm using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm
- I am injecting VMs from DI
- I would like to do this "as MVVM as possible" i.e. not binding directly to the model - keep the separation M-V-VM clear (even if it meant overengineered code)

I have created custom high level `CanvasControl` which would bind to `ObservableCollection<Polygon>` and it's code behind took care of rendering, like:

```cs
var geometry = CanvasGeometry.CreatePolygon(session, polygon.Points);

foreach (var cutout in polygon.Cutouts)
{
    var cutoutGeometry = CanvasGeometry.CreatePolygon(session, cutout);
    geometry = geometry.CombineWith(cutoutGeometry, Matrix3x2.Identity, CanvasGeometryCombine.Exclude);
}

session.DrawGeometry(geometry, lineColor, PolygonLineThickness);
```

My `Polygon` model looks like this:

```cs
public class Polygon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Vector2> Points { get; init; }
    public List<List<Vector2>> Cutouts { get; init; }

    void Rotate(double degrees) { ... }
    ...
}
```

My problem is, how do I get the polygon object in the custom canvas code behind so I'm not referencing model directly from view thus violating MVVM? This binding should be two way, so when I for example drag the polygon, it will be processed in the canvas code and reflected back to the source collection.

My ideas were:

**Create `ObservableCollection<PolygonViewModel>`** and in my ViewModel do something like `polygons.Select(p => new PolygonViewModel(p));` and CustomCanvas would bind to this - however since custom controls should not be tied to MVVM (like we don't have things like TextBoxViewModel), this doesn't seem like the right way. Also I don't *think* it's clean to get some VMs from DI and some create manually (?)

**Create some `PolygonItem` object in the view layer.** This seems like the right way because the control would stay standalone. This would bind to `ObservableCollection<Polygon>` with a value converter between those two. However I don't see how this would be possible. If the converter was in the VM layer, it cannot see the `PolygonItem` in the view layer. If it was in the view layer, it cannot see the `Polygon` in the model layer.

Am I even approaching this right?

Comment: Is this UWP? or WinUI 3?

Comment: This is WinUI 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to ask yourself,

*Do polygons need to live outside my custom CanvasControl?*

and if the answer is *NO*, then keep everything inside the custom CanvasControl, meaning in code-behind.

But if the answer is *YES*, here's a sample code:

**AwesomeCanvas.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace AwesomeCanvasControlSample;

public sealed class AwesomeCanvas : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ItemsSource),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(AwesomeCanvas),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(SelectedItem),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(AwesomeCanvas),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public AwesomeCanvas()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(AwesomeCanvas);
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="AwesomeCanvasControlSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:AwesomeCanvasControlSample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddPolygonCommand}"
                Content="Add polygon" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.RemovePolygonCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Bind AwesomeCanvasControl.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                Content="Remove polygon" />
        </StackPanel>
        <local:AwesomeCanvas
            x:Name="AwesomeCanvasControl"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Polygons, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AwesomeCanvasControlSample;

public class Polygon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Polygon> polygons = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    private void AddPolygon()
    {
        Polygons.Add(new Polygon() { Id = Polygons.Count + 1 });
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void RemovePolygon(Polygon polygon)
    {
        Polygons.Remove(polygon);
    }
}
```

There are different opinions but IMHO, **MVVM** is not about the separation of **View | ViewModel | Model**, it's more about direction of dependencies **View -> ViewModel -> Model**:

- **Models** should never know about **ViewModels** and **Views**.
- **ViewModels** can know about the **Models** but never about the **Views**.
- **Views**..., you get the rest...

So, in this case, there's nothing wrong to pass Polygons (Model) to the View without wrapping it in PolygonViewModel.

Comment: Yes, my VM needs to work with those polygons, UI is just a way to manipulate them, but in the end I will need them in my services once they are positioned. I also want to make something like a command bar with buttons like rotate etc. -- In your `AwesomeCanvas` you have type `object` - are you counting on that it would know about the model in the rendering code? -- And yeah, I know I *can* reference Model from View when it makes sense (like here), but I was curious what would be a way to do this if I wanted to fully comply with MVVM. Maybe it would be best to make a control with its CanvasVM?

Comment: I'm using ``object`` because it's the common type you see as ``ItemsSource`` for other controls. Of course, you can change it to whatever you need. It seems that you are interested in a **PolygonViewModel** class but I'd go that way if there's a need to add some logic or it's hard to use raw ``Polygon`` in **Views**. I would avoid creating just a wrapper. About CanvasVM, again, IMHO, I would never do that. A control (Custom or User), should be just its *.xaml and its *.xaml.cs. I would include everything inside the control.

Comment: I have one more question (or two). Since you are talking about logic in `PolygonViewModel`, if I have methods like `polygon.Rotate(deg)`, these should go to the `Polygon` or rather that VM? If model, that's the end of the question. If VM, and I were to create `PolygonViewModel`, would I instantiate these manually (even though the rest of VMs is injected) or via some DI way?

Comment: It always depends but in this scenario, I would call ``polygon.Rotate(deg)`` in MainPageViewModel. Still, no need for ``PolygonViewModel``.